# What is the css selector to scrape this part of the html

Tags: html, web-scraping, css-selectors

```
<span class="_c24 _2ieq">
<div><span class="accessible_elem">Birthday</span>
</div>
     <div>April 28, 1998</div>
</span>
```

I am web scraping and wanna extract the date present in this div . How to use the css Selector to extract the dates of a webpage if it has the above given structure ?

Also the class="_c24 _2ieq" may vary overtime and only the "accessible_elem" class remains all time , so how to have my css selectors such that it selects the div with the dates ?

Comment: What are you using for scraping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `accessible_elem` class doesn't help you because CSS won't let you go up the DOM tree. This CSS is simple, but should work no matter what the outer span class may be.

```css
span div:last-of-type {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="_c24 _2ieq">
  <div>
    <span class="accessible_elem">Birthday</span>
  </div>
  <div>April 28, 1998</div>
</span>
```